# Running coroutines concurrently not working properly in pythong/asyncio

Tags: python, multithreading, websocket, python-asyncio

I have a publisher/subscriber architecture running on my websocket server, where the publisher runs in one thread, and the websocket server in another. I connect to the server from the publisher over localhost, and the server distributes the published messages to any other connected clients on the `/sub` path. However, since the publisher thread not always has new data to publish, it  has a tendency to disconnect after a timeout of 50 sec. To fix this, I implemented a heartbeat ping function:

```py
async def ping(websocket):
   while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(30)
        print("[%s] Pinging server..." % datetime.now())
        await websocket.send('ping')
```

This keeps the publisher from disconnecting. However, when I'm trying to run this concurrently with the coroutine that sends the actual data, I cannot get both `ping()` and `send_data()` to run in parallel. I've tried just `await`ing both functions as well as `asyncio.gather()` (which [according to documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently) is supposed to run tasks concurrently) as well as flipping the order, but it seems like in all cases only the first function call is ran.

My thread class for reference:

```py
class Publisher(threading.Thread):
    """
    Thread acting as the websocket publisher
    Pulls data from the data merger queue and publishes onto the websocket server
    """
    def __init__(self, loop, q, addr, port):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.loop = loop
        self.queue = q
        self.id = threading.get_ident()
        self.addr = addr
        self.port = port
        self.name = 'publisher'
        print("Publisher thread started (ID:%s)" % self.id)

    def run(self):
        self.loop.run_until_complete(self.publish())
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()

    async def ping(self, websocket):
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(30)
            print("[%s] Pinging server..." % datetime.now())
            await websocket.send('ping')
            
    async def send_data(self, websocket):
        while True:
                try:
                    msg = json.dumps(self.queue.get()) # Get the data from the queue
                    print(msg)
                    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
                    if not msg:
                        print("No message")
                        break
                    await websocket.send(msg)
                except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError:
                    print("Connection closed")
                    break           
        
    async def publish(self):
        uri = 'ws://' + str(self.addr) + ':' + str(self.port) + '/pub'
        async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
            await asyncio.gather(
                self.ping(websocket),
                self.send_data(websocket)
            )
```

Comment: The problem is that the queue you are using is a threading queue, not an async queue, so `self.queue.get()` is blocking the coroutine and with it the whole event loop. Why do you run the publisher in a thread? It should be possible to convert it into an asyncio task, and run it in the same event loop where the websocket server runs. Then they can communicate with an `asyncio.Queue()`, and everything will (should) work out of the box.

Comment: @user4815162342 I collect data from GPS modules (each in their own thread), therefore I use a regular `queue.Queue()` to collect all this data in a thread safe manner. I run the publisher in another thread because it seemed like the natural thing to do, but the event loop in the example I posted is the same event loop as the server runs in, so I'm not sure if it makes any practical difference.

Comment: You can use an `asyncio.Queue` and post things to the queue using `loop.call_soon_threadsafe(self.queue.put_nowait, item)`. Then you can `await self.queue.get()` in asyncio, and the event loop won't be blocked on the wait.